# Set default screen brightness to 'auto'

Tags: java, android, brightness

I am using the following code to get the screen brightness.

```
    private static int getBrightness(Context context) {
    try {
        int brightness = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        return brightness;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me the current brightness = 102 (which is correct). But I need to set the default brightness mode to 'auto'. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Settings.System.putInt(cResolver,
         Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,
         Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
```

don't forget to apply permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

See [Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE)

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, 1);
```

manual 0, auto 1

But it's more appropriate to use the constants as Ken suggested:)